# How to prove this property for an open subset of a topological vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $U \subset X$ be open. Prove the following:

> For every $x \in U$ and for every $a \in X$, there exists a $\epsilon
> >  0$ such that $x + sa \in U$ for all $s \in (- \epsilon, \epsilon)$.

I was wondering if I need convexity of $U$ for this? I don't see how I can prove it.

If I let $x \in U, a \in X$, then I know there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x, \delta) \subset U$. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What if you find an $\varepsilon$ such that $||\varepsilon a || < \delta$? Then $x+sa \in B(x,\delta)$ right?, maybe you can continue from here?

Answer (score 3):

The mapping
$$
f(s):=x + sa
$$
is continuous from $\mathbb R$ to $X$. We have $f(0) \in U$ and hence $0\in f^{-1}(U)$. In addition, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, so it contains an open interval around zero.

Comment: Wow. Very elegant answer!